# AWS CLI: A tale of 2 date returns

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm writing a script to help purchase a spot instance.  I have created a script that works on my mac via terminal, but not on my Linux VM.  Here is the script:

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-price-history --instance-types g2.2xlarge --product-descriptions "Windows" --start-time `date +%s`
```

As best I can tell, in both environments running `date +%s` from the command line by itself returns a similarly formatted value: 1472411661

On the Mac, I get the expected list of spot prices.  (3 different prices)

On Linux, I receive `Invalid value ('1472411661') for param timestamp:StartTime of type timestamp` error.

On Linux, when I remove the `--start-time variable`, I receive a huge list of spot prices, which is what I expect based on those filters.

My setup:

- Mac OS Sierra (beta), AWS CLI installed via Homebrew
- Ubuntu Trusty (with all updates), AWS CLI installed via APT-GET

Any ideas why it works in Mac Terminal but on when connected to my LinuxVM?

Comment: Run the command `aws --version` to see what version of the CLI tool you are running  in both places.

Comment: Linux: aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.4.0+, Mac: aws-cli/1.10.59 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.0.0 botocore/1.4.49.   Maybe I need to see how to install a higher version of AWS CLI on my Linux machine?

Comment: That was it  Thanks for pointing out my stupidity.  I fell into the trap of assuming the APT-GET package would be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the comment from Mark B above:  the APT package on Linux was not the most up to date version of AWS CLI.  When I installed it via PIP, it installed the latest version and it worked as expected.